# crashlytics Unity iOS : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crashlytics, google-fabric

Our game crashed twice for iPhone X user in the past day and honestly i have no idea on how to even start reading the crash log, here is the full log : 
https://pastebin.com/z1rGYSXR

(some of it because of stackoverflow requirement)

```
0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  GLEngine                       0x1a68dbb3c gleRunVertexSubmitARM + 2848
1  GLEngine                       0x1a68d89ac gleSetVertexArrayFunc + 144
2  GLEngine                       0x1a68835a0 glDrawElements_IMM_ES2Exec + 1144
3  upjump                         0x104ff2a44 GfxDeviceGLES::DrawBufferRanges(GfxBuffer*, VertexStreamSource const*, int, DrawBuffersRange const*, int, VertexDeclaration*, ShaderChannelMask, unsigned long, bool) (GfxDeviceGLES.cpp:1899)
```

(couldn't post here cause its too long and get the "post is mostly code" error)

thank you!

Comment: You are using plugins so it's hard to tell you if the problem is from your code or once of the plugin. I encourage you to make a copy of your project, remove all plugins from the copy and see if it crashes too.

Comment: @Programmer yeah am almost sure its one of the plugins/assets, and unfortunately it would be almost impossible to run the game without them, but is there any "documentation" or something to help understand crashlytics log ?

Comment: You can't fix a plugin since you don't have the source code. Do what I said in my first comment, find out the plugin then go to their Github page and report the issue with the error you have. Also, no crashing plugin is worth including in your game for any reason.